Mapping Interior of Unit Circle to Exterior of Ellipse
I've been looking for some information on how to map the interior of the unit disk to the exterior of an ellipse. I have read some things about the Joukowsky transform and how it can be utilized to achieve this. After looking at this post, Conformally mapping an ellipse into the unit circle, here is what I thought of:
Let $\Omega = \left\{w = u+iv: \frac{u^2}{a^2} + \frac{v^2}{b^2} > 1\right\}$, where $a > b$. Does the map $z \mapsto \frac{z}{\alpha}+\frac{\beta}{z},$ where $\beta + \alpha = a$ and $\beta - \alpha = b$ conformally map the interior of the unit disk onto $\Omega$?

Let's look at the case $a = 2, b = 1$. Then
$$
\alpha = 1/2\\
\beta = 3/2
$$
so your map is
$$
(x + iy) \to 2(x + iy) + \frac{3}{2}\frac{x - iy}{x^2 + y^2}.
$$
Let's evaluate that at $ z = i$. I get
$$
2i + \frac{3}{2} (-i) = \frac12 i
$$
Sadly, that point is solidly inside the ellipse defined by
$$
\frac{u^2}{4} + \frac{v^2}{1} = 1
$$
which does, after all, contain the point $(0, 1)$ (or the complex number $i$, if you want to think of it that way). Because $z = i$ is sent well inside that ellipse, $z = i -.00001$ is also sent inside. That means you haven't got things quite right.
